# Not updating records in table through stored procedure ,Not showing any errors . resulting as zero rows affected

Tags: sql-server

```
create procedure dailyconuntupdate
(
@count bigint,
@GeneratedDate datetime = NULL
)
as 
IF @GeneratedDate is null
set @GeneratedDate= getdate()
Begin
update sentcount set Sentcontentcount= @count;
 End

Exec dbo.dailyconuntupdate @count=1000
```

Comment: [It works fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a37a6e8caf42377774b73fb56aa0c4f). Is there more code that you aren't showing us? Or are you running the entire script as is, and missing a [batch separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) to separate your create procedure statement from the one calling it? Of note, you never actually use `@GeneratedDate`, so your logic to set it to today if it is null is redundant

Comment: Not running entire script as is, First saved procedure and passed variable value.

Comment: In that case I can only assume there is more code that you haven't shared? Are you able to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So what does `EXEC sp_helptext N'dbo.dailyconuntupdate'` return for you? If your database user's default schema isn't `dbo` then I expect it's not what you're expecting.